# Laravel MySQL join three tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

```
1. Table 'Element'
|id|name|

2. Table 'Group' 
|id|name|show_all|

3. Table 'Element_to_group'
|id|element_id|group_id|
```

I need to show records from Table 3 based on group_id, and if in table Group -> show_all is 1, all records from table Element.

```
$records = DB::table('element as e')
->select('e.name as name')
->join('element_to_group as etg', 'etg.element_id', 'e.id')
->join('group as g', 'etg.body_group_id', 'g.id')
->where('etg.group_id', XXX)
->orWhere('g.show_all', 1)
->get();
```

The first join returns results as it should, but the second does nothing -- it's ignored. What am I missing?

Comment: Change the `->get()` to `->toSql()` then `dd($records)` to see what the SQL looks like.